# How to uninstall the opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 and installed 4.1.2.30 in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have the error as per message below:
cannot import name '_registerMatType' from 'cv2.cv2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

I saw a lot of comment saying we need to uninstall the opencv-python.May i know how can i do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to uninstall - `python -m pip uninstall opencv-python-headless``

to install - `python -m pip install Colab`

for more info you can look in `pypi` and search for the library

Comment: Hi,May i know how can i do that? Any tutorial or guidance for this part? as i am new to the python and colab as well

Comment: Run: !pip uninstall opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62 && pip install opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30 in  colab code cell.